# JavaScript Array.map() appends commas to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dom

I'm attempting to render a few lottery results from [here](https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json). 
I am getting all the data just fine, but want to combine the winning_numbers, mega_ball, and multiplier values to render to the page like this:

[image]

Instead what I am getting is the numbers but with commas rendered to the DOM as well like this shows:

[image]

```
const url = 'https://data.ny.gov/resource/h6w8-42p9.json';

$.get(url, (data) => {
// Deconstruct Array Data
[latest, one, two, three] = data;

const pastResults = [one, two, three]

// Removed A Block of CODE for StackOverflow dealing with latest result since it works fine.

pastResults.map(num => {

  const numsArray = num.winning_numbers.split(" ");
  numsArray.push(num.mega_ball);
  numsArray.push("x" + num.multiplier.split("")[1]);
  console.log(numsArray);

  pastResultsBlock.append(`
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="animated flipInY past-result-item box-shadow">
        <div class="past-result-date">${moment(num.draw_date).format("MMM Do")}</div>
        <div class="past-result-numbers">
          ${numsArray.map(number => `<span>${number}</span>`)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    `)
  })

})
```

In the console the array looks just fine. but when it renders in the DOM there is a "," comma after every ...

Any help and feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a JSFiddle link just in case. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SavSamoylov/zzzt2unn/1/)

Comment: I can't see anything that'd introduce a comma in your code. You've not got a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element declared in your CSS have you?

Comment: @fubar The code is calling `toString` on the array returned from `.map` which introduces commas.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - good to know, cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply join them explicitly instead of relying on the default `Array::toString` method.

```
// Change
`...${numsArray.map(number => `<span>${number}</span>`)}...`
// to
`...${numsArray.map(number => `<span>${number}</span>`).join("")}...`
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @SavSamoylov You can accept this question if it solves your problem.

Comment: It wasn't letting me do it within the first 5 minutes. BUt again, thank you.

Comment: @SavSamoylov No problem, take your time :) I'm glad to hear that your issue is resolved.